# Actions on Google Account Linking not working "Serviceid not configured"

Tags: actions-on-google

I built a custom app for Google Assistant and basicly everything works fine.

Now I added account linking regarding the google documentation (OAuth 2.0 with Authorization Code Flow). Also this is working fine in test environment.

**Now the problem:** When testing from my device (Google Assistant App on smartphone) the following error appears local on the device when linking the app through the Discover tab:

"ServiceId is not configured".

And no https request from Google is made to my OAuth server.

I made hard research through all platforms but I cannot find any place where I could configure the so called ServiceId.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Account linking does not work from the directory listing when the app is in testing (Not in production).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I guess you wanted to write "does _not_ work"?

Comment: Corrected. Thanks!